# Compare one Array List object with the next one

Tags: java, file, arraylist, compare

Hello guys here my  Code

```
public class Main {
    public static List<String> globalList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        globalList = new ArrayList<String>();
        File folder = new File("\\Documents\\Folder);
                File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                for(File file : listOfFiles) {
                    dosomething(file);
                }
                for( String t : globalList)
                {
                    System.out.println(t);
                }
    }

    public static void dosomething(File file) {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                globalList.add(str);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

In my folder i have a few files. Every file contains a line of information so i took every line and saved the lines to my Arraylist `globalList`. Now i want to compare one object in my ArrayList with the next one, is this possible?
Just like: if (firstobj == nextobj) remove it.

**Edit**
Sorry guys i forgot something to write....
The problem is, the line i need to delete arent completly the same, because they start with ah generated number, this number is important for those files so i cant just delete it...
So i need to compare one part of my line if its the same i need to remove it.

One example:
10133;1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;30;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX
10134;1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;30;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX
10135;1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;15;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX

So now you see the first 2 lines are almost the same except the starting number, i need to find those lines and delete them. Because of changes i cant do somthing like `if(list.contains("10135;1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;15;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX") )`.

Comment: of course this is possible `globalList.get(0).equals(globalList.get(1))`. But what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @MoritzPetersen i need to read in at list 100files (when my programm is finish). And in some of those files (not in all) are lines which i need to delete.

Comment: Do you want to avoid lines duplicate ? Is that this ?

Comment: You want to delete entries which only differs in generated id?

Comment: How do you define "similar enough"?

Comment: are you sure that for every string you have to skip the string before  first ' ; '  to check for duplicates

Comment: @Flown  i need to delet line where "XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;30;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX" this part of the String is the same

Comment: @Harish yes because this string woult bi different everytime

Comment: @k.bo: Did you try forming a substring of the part you think will be same and then getting the those lines with that similar part and simply removing them? Try storing each element of the file in a string and then comparing them.

Comment: @k.bo check the answer I added. here you don't need to specifically check every element whether it matches or not by writing huge for loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case if you don't want to check if the part string contains in the list every time then it will take hours if you have a hugefile instead you can use a `Set` which does not allow duplicates. Unique feature of set is that it does not allow duplicates so instead of taking list of string wrap the string in a custom class and then override the equals and hashcode implementation of the class so that it will not consider the the part of string until the first occurrence of semicolon in the string.

Finally found the working code..

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MyString 
{
    public static Set<MyString> globalSet; 
    private String line;
    public String getLine(){
        return this.line;
    }

    public void  setLine(String newLine){
        this.line = newLine;  
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\hbm5cf7\\Documents\\NewF");
        globalSet = new HashSet<MyString>(); 
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for(File file : listOfFiles) {
            dosomething(file);
        }

        for(MyString t : globalSet)
        {
            System.out.println(t.getLine());
        }

    }
    public static void dosomething(File file)
    {

        try {

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            MyString str;
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                str = new MyString();
                str.setLine(line);
                globalSet.add(str);
            }
            in.close();



        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((line == null) ? 0 : line.split(";", 2)[1].hashCode());
        return result;
    }

     @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj)
        { 

            if (this == obj)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.line.equals(((MyString) obj).getLine())) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            String splitString = ((MyString) obj).getLine().split(";", 2)[1];   
            if(this.line.endsWith(splitString))
            {
                return true;  
            }
            return false; 
         }

}
```

by overriding the equals and hashcode methods you can decide which one is duplicate and which is not depending upon your requirement

Comment: I tried to test that one, but i think im to stupid to implement this right in my code... i got an error at  this line: `if (this.line.equals(obj.line))`

Comment: @k.bo yes my bad  it will be because line is private object.Now I modified my code check it.

Comment: @K.bo I didn't do that code in my eclipse. I've just  typed that in here. So just look at the implementation and try to use that way.

Comment: I dont get it =(

Comment: what I'm trying to say is I didn't compile the code myself but given the implementation way

Comment: Yes yes, i tried it now but i got this Exception: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException".  Maybe i did it wrong now idk...

Comment: can you start a chat so we can discuss now

Comment: Öhm i guess my Level is to low to start a chat here? Or where i can do that... Sorry im new

Comment: sorry not possible but tell me at which line you are getting nullpointer exception

Comment: `globalSet.add(str);`  at this line.

Comment: i post an answer with the whole code maybe i did something wrong.

Comment: did you initialize that in main method globalSet = new HastSet<MyString>();

Comment: ah sorry yes i forgot that one. Now the Exception is away. Whats the best way now to check which lines are still there and which are deleted?

Comment: I didn't get  you

Comment: How i print out the lines now?

Comment: When i do this the output is just one line, but it have to be more then one. So i think this wont fix my problem or im just too stupid

Comment: i posted my answer check it out.

Comment: @k.bo I updated the answer. firstly you are creating new set for every in do something method file so it is contain one file data only and secondly new object is not created for every iteration so same object is passed to Set which will not accept as the first condition we set to equals method that if I pass same object don't add it to set. Now this may work

Comment: Okei... Thanks for help buddy, but now the output still contains those lines i need to find and delete :S

Comment: @k.bo I've updated the answer after testing it with the data you provided and its printing expected results now

Comment: Now the line with "30" is there, instead of the line with 15. 
And is it possible that the line stay in the same order?

Comment: for the order you can use LinkedHashSet instead of HashSet while constructing the globalSet and the rest stays same. LinkedHashSet  preserves the order of inserts to the set so the natural order if adding the values to the set will not be disturbed

Comment: Okei thanks
`10129;1;Trägertour 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;30;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;WBSU
10135;1;Trägertour 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;15;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;WBSU'` now i have this problem, one line is stil there...

Comment: the 2 lines you mentioned in your comment has different values after 1st semi colon

Comment: yep but always need to say delete the line, its the same line in this substring: ;Trägertour 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;. Fot the understanding i need to delete every line except the line which is different. If you see file content 3, i need to delete there every line except this line : `10135;1;Trägertour 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;15;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;WBSU`

Comment: then Its not about ignoring the first part of string but deep scanning of the string

Comment: yea i need just another compare, who deepscaans the string and delete this one line too, do you have any idea?

Comment: Based on the value between the semi colon which you want to compare adapt hashcode and equals method by splitting the string and passing the required value

Comment: hmm okei im gonna try it

Comment: Hmm i  dont get it.

Comment: Can you help me? I still have this problem

Comment: I really don't know what you want to achieve. so if as now you have ':' as a delimiter so decide which part of string you want to consider and which part of string you want to ignore to decide whether a string is duplicate. and implement hashcode and equals method according to it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can use `equals` method to compare the lines. However, you should rather compare the lines while reading the files and not store the file content in a `list` and compare. E.g.:

```
try(BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));){
    String line1 = reader1.readLine();
    String line2 = reader2.readLine();
    if(line1 != null && line1.equals(line2)){
       //Do something
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    //Exception handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

If you have the same generated number followed by an escape character like semicolon you can get the index of the first semicolon and get the substring that start from the next character:

```
public static void dosomething(File file) {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            globalList.add(str);

            String subString = str.substring(str.indexOf(";") + 1, str.length());

            for(Iterator<String> iter = globalList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
            {
                String elem = (String) iter.next();

                if(elem.contains(subString))
                   iter.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Another version:

```
public static void dosomething(File file) {
    try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

                // remove spaces from beginning and end of the input string
                str = str.trim();
                String subString = str.substring(str.indexOf(";") + 1, str.length());

                boolean match = false;
                // search in globalList for a match
                for(String elem : globalList)
                {
                    if(elem.contains(subString)){
                       match = true;
                       break;
                    }
                }
                // if it doesn't contain the string add it
                if(!match)
                   globalList.add(str);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, im so sorry dude, i forgot to say somthing important. Can you read the "edit". Thanks  a lot!

Comment: edited, but i assumed you have always a semicolon after the generated number. Is this correct? or it changes?

Comment: Yes i need somthing like this, but my problem is i need to compare every line, like if the next line contains the same text ";1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;30;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX" delet me.
In the end i need to check around 100 files, and  i need to go check oke if the next line the same delete me ...

Comment: Oh damn son xD I love you so much, "Another Version" is excatly what wanted. It works well it delets the lines i have to. But one problem now is, one line Still stays. For Example: 
`line1 (same)
line2 (same)
line3 (same)
line4(different)` Now line 2,3 are deleted but line1 is still there

Comment: Glad it works! which line? is it different from the others in something? maybe a space?

Comment: @amincoderozer This line is same like the 2 oder the programm deletes, (or not saving in the ArrayList ) 
I know its compliacated for understanding. In those 100 files i have do find those files where all lines are the same except the last. But with your code its working great execept it doesnt delete the last one which was same like the lines theyre already deleted...

Comment: Nah de line is still there. 
Hmm its realy difficult. Maybe need  to add there somthing wo checks: the next line is alsmost the same so dont save me. 
Because i need to check okei the lines befor was same so delete, and for fixing the problem i need to check, contains the next string where ";1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;" is the same.

Comment: @amicoderozer wow if he has 5000 lines ,then you have to check  4999 times just to insert an element at 5000th position times. those are files man !

Answer (score 0):

I think you're simply trying to ensure that you end up with a single list containing every 'unique' line from every file.

If this is the case you could use an implementation of Set (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) in place of your `globaList` such as HashSet https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

The set implementation will ensure that no duplicates are added.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
  Iterator<String> iterator =  globalList.iterator();
  String lastObj = null;
  String nextObj = null;
  while (iterator.hasNext()){
    nextObj = iterator.next();
    if(lastObj == null ){
      lastObj = nextObj;
    }
    else {
      if(lastObj.equals(nextObj)){
        iterator.remove();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Im so sorry i forgot somthing important can you please read the  Edit part, but thanks for your answer yes i need somthing like that.

Answer (score 0):

@Harish Barma

Files Content:
File1:

```
2;XXXX;XXXX;;P;XX;XXX;1N410;20170719;1;;;0;0;1;999;1;1;;
10000;1;XXXX 096;1410;Autotour 1N410;15;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXX
10001;2;XXXX 097;1410;Autotour 1N410;10;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXX
10002;3;XXXX 098;1410;Autotour 1N410;13;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXX
10003;4;XXXX 099;1410;Autotour 1N410;19;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXX
10004;5;XXXX 100;1410;Autotour 1N410;15;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXX
```

File2:

```
2;XXXX;XXXX;;P;XX;XXXX;3A680;20170726;1;;;0;0;1;999;1;1;;
10082;1;XXX S146;3680;Autotour 3A680;5;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXx
10083;2;XXX S147;3680;Autotour 3A680;8;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXX
10084;3;XXX 095;3680;Autotour 3A680;6;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX
```

File3:

```
2;XXXX;XXXX;;P;XX;XXX;4M100;20170719;1;;;0;0;1;999;1;1;;
10129;1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;30;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX
10130;1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;30;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX
10131;1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;30;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX
10132;1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;30;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX
10133;1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;30;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX
10134;1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;30;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX
10135;1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;15;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX
```

(File 5-100 can cointain same lines like file 3 or different lines like file 1 or 2.)
Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class MyString 
{
    public static Set<MyString> globalSet; 
    private String line;
    public String getLine(){
        return this.line;
    }
    public void  setLine(String newLine){
        this.line = newLine;  
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
    if (this == obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.line.equals(((MyString) obj).getLine())) //compiler said i need to do this so...
    {
        return true;
    }
    String splitString = ((MyString) obj).getLine().split(";", 2)[1];   //compiler said i need to do this so...
     if(this.line.endsWith(splitString))
     {
         return true;  
     }
    return false; 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\V90xxxxPCN\\Documents\\Neuer Ordner");
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();



           for(File file : listOfFiles) {
               dosomething(file);
           }

          for(MyString t : globalSet)
        {
            System.out.println(t.getLine());
        }


    }
    public static void dosomething(File file)
    {

        try {
            globalSet = new HashSet<MyString>();    
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            MyString str = new MyString();
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                 str.setLine(line);
                globalSet.add(str);
            }



            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
2;XXXX;XXXX;;P;XX;XXX;1N410;20170719;1;;;0;0;1;999;1;1;;
    10000;1;XXXX 096;1410;Autotour 1N410;15;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXX
    10001;2;XXXX 097;1410;Autotour 1N410;10;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXX
    10002;3;XXXX 098;1410;Autotour 1N410;13;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXX
    10003;4;XXXX 099;1410;Autotour 1N410;19;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXX
    10004;5;XXXX 100;1410;Autotour 1N410;15;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXX
2;XXXX;XXXX;;P;XX;XXXX;3A680;20170726;1;;;0;0;1;999;1;1;;
    10082;1;XXX S146;3680;Autotour 3A680;5;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXx
    10083;2;XXX S147;3680;Autotour 3A680;8;0;K;0;;;0;2;;XXXX
    10084;3;XXX 095;3680;Autotour 3A680;6;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX
2;XXXX;XXXX;;P;XX;XXX;4M100;20170719;1;;;0;0;1;999;1;1;;
10135;1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;15;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX
```

Output:

```
10135;1;XXXX 110;4100;Autotour 4M100;15;0;K;0;;;0;2;3;XXXX
```